# I am getting unwanted comma in my markup when I fetch from local JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to display data from a local JSON file using fetch. The data is displaying correctly except I am getting an unwanted comma in my markup

This is the script to display the data from Blog.json file

```
    fetch('./src/Blog.json')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response;
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.json();
    })
    .then(function (blogData) {
        const html = blogData.map(
            (data) =>
                ` 
        <h3>${data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName}</h4>
        <h4>${data.username}</h2>
        <p>${data.aboutAuthor}</p>
   `
        );
        document.getElementById('appData').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Fetch problem show: ' + err.message);
    });
```

This is the json data from Blog.json

```
[
    {
    "username": "officialrajdeepsingh",
    "firstName": "Rajdeep",
    "lastName": "Singh",
    "gender": "Male",
    "aboutAuthor": "Read Book, Music Lover and Web Developer"
    },
    {
    "username": "Esme",
    "firstName": "Esme",
    "lastName": "Sullivan",
    "gender": "FeMale",
    "aboutAuthor": "Graet Book Reader"
    },
    {
    "username": "Dennis",
    "firstName": "Dennis",
    "lastName": "Thompson",
    "gender": "Male",
    "aboutAuthor": " Love Football, Music Lover"
    },
    {
    "username": "Amelia",
    "firstName": "Amelia",
    "lastName": "Sanchez",
    "gender": "feMale",
    "aboutAuthor": "Book Writer, Music Lover and Web Developer"
    }
]
```

This returns the expected output except there is a comma displayed in the markup following data.aboutAuthor

example html display:

Rajdeep Singh
officialrajdeepsingh
Read Book, Music Lover and Web Developer

,
Esme Sullivan
Esme
Graet Book Reader

,

notice the commas present in the markup after mapping over the array of objects

Comment: Unless the JSON file is being served along with the HTML/JS, then it won't be available to the browser.

Comment: you need to run `join`. you have an array. if you did `htm += string;` it'd be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
const html = blogData.map((data) => `<some HTML string
```

your `html` variable is now an array of strings. If you then insert it with

```
.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

the array of strings will be implicitly converted to a single string, which is done internally by `.join(',')`ing the array, adding those commas.

Either explicitly join by the empty string first with:

```
const arrayOfBlogHTML = blogData.map(
  // ...
);
document.getElementById('appData').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', arrayOfBlogHTML.join(''));
```

Or insert the HTML in each iteration inside the callback.

```
const appData = document.getElementById('appData');
for (const oneAuthorData of blogData) {
    appData.insertAdjacentHTML(
        'beforeend',
        `
            <h3>${oneAuthorData.firstName + ' ' + oneAuthorData.lastName}</h4>
            <h4>${oneAuthorData.username}</h2>
            <p>${oneAuthorData.aboutAuthor}</p>
        `
    );
}
```

On another note, `appData` makes for a somewhat odd name for an ID of an element because you're already using the `blogData` variable name to refer to the array of objects in the response. You might consider naming the ID something else, like `authorsContainer` (because it'll end up being the container for all the authors).